# CoordinatorLayout with Tabs in android?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new for `CoordinatorLayout` i want to use `coordinatorLayout` in my application but it cause some problem in display `CollapsingToolbarLayout` view.

[image]

i want to design view like whatsApp screen `Tabs` in `Coordinatorlayout`

My XML Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="24dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </LinearLayout>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        // child view

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I Found Solution for Tabs in CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

         /***
                   Here You can add custom layout
                 **/


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The `layout_behavior` attribute in `ViewPager` does it!

Comment: The ide does flag the string resource as not found, but seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

CoordinatorLayout is delicate sometimes, I suggest you to follow the next example using it as a base and adding more complexity step by step if you need:

https://gist.github.com/RicardAparicio/f41523daaa0edbe0b4399549fff4da3f

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"but it cause some problem in display" doesn't say what kind of problem You had, glad You found the solution though.

There is indeed problem in both 22.2.1 and 23.0.1 support libraries with TabLayout and ViewPager in CoordinatorLayout while using fitsSystemWindows="true". While using RecyclerView and scrolling it up TabLayout header goes into status bar while it's background color is not being pinned.

I might only imply that above was **one of Your problems**, if yes then removing fitsSystemWindows is not best solution as application will loose a lot of it's look in 5.0+ Android.

It is not good solution either but I managed to fix this issue by adding nested android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout, but if You use DrawerLayout there, then nothing is needed as shown in this example: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare